# Proving Hadamard lemma: how to apply FTC in first step?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I wanted to prove Hadamard's lemma but got stuck on the first step:

Let $f \in C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Then there exist $g_i \in C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ such that

$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + \sum_{i =1}^n g_i(x) (x-x_0)$$

on some neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Proof:

I want to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but in $n$-dimensions. Something like this:

$$ f(x) = \color{red}{f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x {d \over dt} f(t) dt} = f(x_0) + \int_{0}^1 {d \over dt} f(t(x-x_0) + x_0)  dt $$

except, the part in $\color{red}{red}$ s not quite right yet (as $t$ is a scalar variable). The reason why I don't know how to fix it is: it should probably be a sum of partial derivatives but then I'd have the same sum in the next equality which is not the case: the last expression in the above display style equation seems fine as it is.

> So my question is: What is the correct expression (between $f(x_0)$
>   and $f(x_0) + \int_{0}^1 {d \over dt} f(t(x-x_0) + x_0)  dt$ )that I
>   should obtain after applying the FTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to apply the FTC you have to introduce an *auxiliary function of one variable* to which it then can be applied.

Fix $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ for the moment, and consider the function
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl(x_0+t(x-x_0)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\ .$$
Then
$$f(x)=\phi(1)=\phi(0)+\int_0^1 \phi'(t)\>dt=f(x_0)+\ldots\quad .$$
Now use the chain rule to express $\phi'(t)$ in terms of partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply chain rule here:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t(x-x_0) +x_0) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (t(x-x_0) + x_0)\cdot \big(x_i - (x_0)_i\big)$$

Comment: I'm sorry but you're not answering my question.

Comment: I keep seeing this form of the chain rule when reading differential geometry material and it doesn't seem to agree with the standard chain rule from calculus. I have asked about it here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854742/strange-form-of-the-chain-rule-i-keep-seeing-in-differential-geometry-material - it would be great if you could take a look at this question if you get a chance!