# Strange form of the chain rule I keep seeing in differential geometry material?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Since I've started reading up on differential geometry I keep coming across something that's bothering me, which is the chain rule. The standard chain rule from calculus is

$$
\frac{df}{dt}(g(t)) = f'(g(t))\cdot \frac{dg}{dt}(t),
$$
which I could also write as
$$
\frac{d f}{dt}(g(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g(t)}(g(t))\cdot \frac{dg}{dt}(t). \quad \quad (1)
$$

Now when I'm reading these differential geometry texts I keep seeing the following strange approach to the chain rule (I'll stay in 1 dimension for simplicity). The function $g$ is specified explicitly and in the simplest case it could be $g(t) = tx$. Then the chain rule is always given as

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d f}{dt}(tx) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx) \frac{d (tx)}{dt}.
\end{align}
$$

Replacing $tx$ by $g(t)$ (so we can compare it with the usual chain rule above) we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \color{red}{ \textbf{x}}}(g(t)) \cdot \frac{dg}{dt}(t), \quad \quad (2)
\end{align}
$$
where I have highlighted the problematic issue. Why have we $x$ in the denominator here instead of $g(t)$ as in the standard chain rule in (1) above?

Some places, among many others, where I have seen this are:

1. [nLab - Hadamard lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hadamard+lemma)
2. [Second answer in this m.se tread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289166/proving-hadamard-lemma-how-to-apply-ftc-in-first-step)
3. The book Introduction to Manifolds by Loring Tu.

So what is going on, is this some 'convention' in which this $x$ actually refers to $g(t) = tx$ or have I misinterpreted something and does the chain rule in (2) somehow agree with the standard chain rule (1)?

Comment: The left-hand side should be $(f \circ g)'(t)$ in the "standard chain rule", not $\frac{df}{dt}(g(t)) = f'(g(t))$.

Comment: You shouldn't write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \color{red}{g(t)}}(g(t))$ because $g(t)$ is not a variable.

Comment: And in the references you cite, $f$ is a multivariate function, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(tx)$ refers to the $i$th partial derivative of $f$ evaluated at the vector $tx$. In the 1-dimensional case you highlight, this is just the usual derivative $f'(tx) = \frac{df}{dx}(tx)$. I actually don't agree with your interpretation of the standard chain rule; you shouldn't write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g(t)}$.

Comment: @AlexProvost: The notation I used is just (a more explicit form of) Liebniz notation, its mentioned in the introduction of the Wikipedia page on the chain rule that they are equivalent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule. By more explicit I mean that I didn't write 'let $z=f(y)$ and $y=g(t)$' first, which is what is done on Wikipedia - this was because I wanted to make it easier to highlight the issue in my question.

Comment: @AlexProvost: And I don't get what you are saying in your first comment. $$(f\circ g)'(t) = (f'\circ g)\cdot g'(t) = f'(g(t)) \cdot \frac{dg}{dt}(t) = \frac{df}{dt}(g(t))$$ It's all the same thing.

Comment: @eurocoder The Leibniz notation relies on specific "variables". In your case, the "variable" for the domain of $g$ if $t$, and the "variable" for the domain of $f$ is $x$. So I still disagree with your notation (and use of partials instead of $d$).

Comment: @eurocoder The second expression in your chain of equalities has no meaning; the first and third agree; and the fourth means $f'(g(t))$, which is not the same as $f'(g(t))g'(t)$.

Comment: @AlexProvost Ok I take your point on the Leibniz notation. Regarding the following comment: the second expression is directly from the introduction of the Wikipedia page on the chain rule. The fourth expression is saying differentiate $f(g(t))$ with respect to $t$, which leads to the chain rule - I don't know why you think it says differentiate $f$ with respect to its argument, which is $g(t)$? For example, page $6$ of Tu's book performs the chain rule on $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}f(p+t(x-p))$ (and the result it gives involves the problematic issue I made my original post about).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80293/discussion-between-alex-provost-and-eurocoder).

Comment: @eurocoder: If you write $\frac{d}{dt} f(g(t))$, then it's OK, but $\frac{df}{dt} (g(t))$ is definitely misleading. In the first case, the operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ acts on the whole expression on its right, but in the second case it acts only on $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we cleared most things up in the comments: in Leibniz notation, and to be very precise, one should write something like

$$ \frac{d(f \circ g)}{dt}(t) = \frac{df}{dx}(g(t)) \frac{dg}{dt}(t).$$

One will often see shorthand forms  like $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t))$ for the left-hand side, but that should never be written as $\frac{df}{dt}(g(t))$.

Comment: Oh and just to mention something else Alex cleared up which might help someone in future - in differential geometry notation is abused such that, in the same expression, the notation $x^i$ may stand for both the coordinates of a particular point $x$ and also the components of some totally unrelated dependent variable used in the denominater of a partial derivative!